# how to test sensormanager on emulator in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, emulation, android-sensors

I am implementing the sensormanager to test if the device moves it should give the accuracy.  But the problem is i dont have device to test this code on.  Is it possible to test this sensormanager code on Emulator??

Thanks in advance,
   Aby

Comment: @mighter thanks for the reply is it possible to test the sensor code in any way.  As i dont have the device, how can i check it.? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenIntents project has a Sensor Simulator, but I do not know if it works with the current sensor API and current versions of Android.

Beyond that, as @Mighter said, no, it is not possible.

Comment: @Aby: Buy or borrow a device. You need one, anyway, for testing other things. Nobody should be shipping an Android application without testing it on at least one device.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you may look at [the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10099084/1324175) in the code I had to make to test the program with the Sensor Simulator.