# Vintage Thermometer component + SensorSimulator on the Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android, android-sensors, android-custom-view

After I found [this nice custom component](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/) that analogly (is this the right word?) displays the temperature read from the Android device's temperature sensor, I wanted to test it with the emulator to see how it works so I've found [this Sensor Simulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator) and altered the component's source to work with it.

I did manage it to work on en emulated device, however I've done a few lucky guesses and'd like to know what exactly I've done :-)

Here are the changes in thermometer's code I had to make to get it to work in conjunction with the temperature sensor simulator:

After importing the `sensorsimulator` classes:

```
import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.Sensor;
import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorEvent;
import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorManagerSimulator;
```

I had to remove the

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
```

Changed

`private SensorManager getSensorManager()`

into

`private SensorManagerSimulator getSensorManager()`

Then the first problem arised. According to *How to use the SensorSimulator in your application* I changed the line:

`return (SensorManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);`

into

`return SensorManagerSimulator.getSystemService(this, SENSOR_SERVICE);`

and that was an error. Instad of `this` I had to use `getContext()`, I am not sure why was that so - maybe because `thermometer` class extends `View` therefore it isn't activity? And instead of `SENSOR_SERVICE` I had to put `Context.SENSOR_SERVICE`.

After that, the next change was:

```
private void attachToSensor() {
    SensorManagerSimulator sensorManager = getSensorManager();
    sensorManager.connectSimulator();
```

Since it seems `sensorsimulator` doesn't implement `getSensorList` I had to replace

```
List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE);
```

with

```
Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE);
```

and to remove

```
if (sensors.size() > 0) {
        Sensor sensor = sensors.get(0);
```

Then, of course I also removed the `else` statement, so the situation when the temeperature sensor is missing would now probably throw an exception when trying to register listener.

At the end, there was one more change I had to make to get rid of the compile errors, for some reason the implementation of `registerListener` in `Sensor Simulator` accepts fewer arguments than android's method so I had to remove the `handler` parameter from

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManagerSimulator.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, handler);
```

Here, I'd like to know why this time I didn't have to use `getContext()` instead of `this`!?

That's about all I had to change, the last thing was to remove unused vars (handler), unused imports (java.util.List) and remove `handler = new Handler();`.

I find this example of custom UI component very interesting and hope someone is going to clarify and maybe polish the code.

Comment: i just had to say its actually digital, because the ui refreshes at certain rates, analog would mean continuous or real-time.

Comment: also put up the complete code instead of what changes you made if theres more than a few, and as far as getContext() vs this, whatever object that you called registerListener inside of is a child of ContextWrapper

Comment: @L7ColWinters: I am not sure if `analogly` was the right word, I wanted to say it **looks like** an analog gauge. About the complete code - the code is quite big and I am not sure if it would be OK to copy/paste someone else's code so I gave the link to the source. Besides, as I can see Vintage Thermometer is well known here on stackoverflow, mentioned in lots of articles.