# App doesn't work on emulator

Tags: java, android, emulation

When I run this piece of code on my phone, everything works fine, yet when I run it on the emulator, the screen of the emulator goes black and nothing after that statement works (gets executed):

```
manager = (SensorManager) this.game.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Check the LogCat for errors. If you didn't declare your Emulator to have that kind of sensor (in the AVD settings), it won't have it and nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to take a look at the this post. It's straight from Android's Xav.
http://tools.android.com/recent/sensoremulation

It should have all the information that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank suggested use a sensor emulator. I don't think the built in emulator can handle sensor API: [how to test sensormanager on emulator in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867172/how-to-test-sensormanager-on-emulator-in-android)

If it works on your device, then just comment it out when you want to run the emulator.. or don't use the emulator. It's slower, and less reliable (obviously). Just use an actual device. You'll have to test on multiple devices anyway because the emulator simply doesn't have the full capabilities and architecture of every device out there.

Hope that steers you in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you may look at  [the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099084/vintage-thermometer-custom-ui-component-sensorsimulator-steps-to-test-the-com) in the code I had to make to test the program with the Sensor Simulator.